# RUST Library for swing/c++/kotlin

Tags: c++, swing, kotlin, rust

I'm working on rust right now because we want to switch to this technology. Today we only use c/c++.  For me now the question arises, if it is possible to provide a library in rust, just like in c/c++. Of course I have seen several examples where rust library is called from c and vice versa. But my question aims at another use case. It is about an API that has a state and not just a stateless function. For example you would have to use an init function to create an object pointer which is returned to the caller. Any other function need this object pointer to provide the needed functions. I would be very surprised if this is not possible but unfortunately I have not found anything. In our Use Case we want to offer the API ( written in rust ) for c++, swing and Kotlin. Of course I know that I could also write this API in c/c++ but the use case relies on Rust for various reasons.
Thanks for your tips 
Greeting
Dusan

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: Your question appears to be lacking a question.

Comment: Hi Eljay, I'm sorry, but I don't understand you. The question is whether I can create an object in Rust which I pass to another program (swing,kotlin,c++) as return value of an init function. 
Here is an example:

/// Here an init function of a rust library
void* obj = rustLibInit();

/// Get me all persons
std::vector<pers> vecPers = getAllPerson(obj);

Is that any easier to understand now?

Comment: Henri Sivonen shared what he had to do for Rust and C++ interop in his [Modern C++ Library in Rust](https://hsivonen.fi/modern-cpp-in-rust/) article.  Could be helpful for your problem.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is a shared library which exposes an interface which can be used from c++ and/or jni for kotlin/swing

Comment: Hi PiRocks, totaly correct.

Comment: In general, the approach is to write the core functionality of your library in Rust, exporting a C interface, which is directly supported by Rust. You can then introduce wrappers for any language with C interoperability, which is most other languages.